# How to drawing animated openlayers linestring path?

Tags: javascript, xml, openlayers, gpx

I using openlaers map api. I want to display animated route in my path like http://jerusalem.com/map#!/tour/the_way_of_the_cross/location/abu_jaafar. How to do that? Thank you.

This is my Java Script, I get data from XML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                          
                var zoom=13

        var map; //complex object of type OpenLayers.Map

        function init() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
                controls:[
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
                maxResolution: 156543.0399,
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                units: 'm',
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            } );

            // Define the map layer
            // Here we use a predefined layer that will be kept up to date with URL changes
            layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
            map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
            layerCycleMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap("CycleMap");
            map.addLayer(layerCycleMap);
            layerMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
            map.addLayer(layerMarkers);

        //   Add the Layer with the GPX Track
            var lgpx = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Descrizione del layer", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "c.php",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GPX()
                }),
                style: {strokeColor: "blue", strokeWidth: 5, strokeOpacity: 0.5},

            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")

            });



            map.addLayer(lgpx);

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer at [Drawing animated openlayers linestring path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410175/drawing-animated-openlayers-linestring-path). It seems to be quite similar.

Here is the important part of the answer:

> ```
> function drawAnimatedLine(startPt, endPt, style, steps, time, fn) {
>     var directionX = (endPt.x - startPt.x) / steps;
>     var directionY = (endPt.y - startPt.y) / steps;
>     var i = 0;
>     var prevLayer;
>     var ivlDraw = setInterval(function () {
>         if (i > steps) {
>             clearInterval(ivlDraw);
>             if (fn) fn();
>             return;
>         }
>         var newEndPt = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(startPt.x + i * directionX, startPt.y + i * directionY);
>         var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([startPt, newEndPt]);
>         var fea = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, {}, style);
>         var vec = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
>         vec.addFeatures([fea]);
>         map.addLayer(vec);
>         if(prevLayer) map.removeLayer(prevLayer);
>         prevLayer = vec;
>         i++;
>     }, time / steps);
> }
> ```
>
> The `time` argument specifies how long you want the animation to last
>   (in milliseconds), and the `steps` specifies how many steps you want
>   to divide the animation into. `fn` is a callback that will be executed
>   when the animation is complete.