# How to rotate pushpin using heading in BING MAPS?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to rotate my pushPin(marker) based on heading on the Bing Map. 
Code is :

```
var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data[index].latitude, data[index].longitude);
    var pushpinOptions = {
        icon: "/images/carMarker.png",
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10, 40),
        typeName: 'carMarker'
    };
    map.entities.remove(carPin);
    carPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, pushpinOptions);
    map.entities.push(carPin);
```

I am able to draw the markers over the map but I am unable to rotate the markers. Please any one help. Thankyou.

Comment: The question regarding openlayer animation has fixed the jsFiddle demo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410175/drawing-animated-openlayers-linestring-path/20481018?noredirect=1#comment58636849_20481018

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting browsers that support CSS3, you can use the `transform` property, see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

```
.carMarker {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

If you don't, then you'll have to generate N version of your icon and change it in the `icon` property and change the anchor to be in the center or your common icon.

See also, [Cross browser way to rotate image using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832131/cross-browser-way-to-rotate-image-using-css)

Comment: How to change this rotation via js?

Comment: Using JS you will want to use htmlContent for the pushpin and then programmatically generate the HTML with inline style values that have the rotate value. Take a look at these examples: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript/   https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/02/05/visualizing-point-based-business-intelligence-data-on-bing-maps/